# Replicate pass encryption from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, cryptojs

I would like to replicate the following PHP code in JS:

```
    $salted = $raw_pass."{".$salt."}";
    $iterations = 5000;
    $digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

    // "stretch" hash
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
    }

    return base64_encode($digest);
```

It's creating a hash from pass and salt, 5000 iterations. This is actually from Symfony's [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php) (I changed the code a bit for the sake of example, sorry for possible typos).

I want to replicate this in JavaScript and I did this:

```
var salted = raw_pass + "{" + salt + "}"
var digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);              

for (var i=0;i<5000;i++){
    digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest+salted);
}

user.password = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(digest)
```

Everything works ok when I create `digest` (I get the same string on both sides), but after it reiterates, I get different hashes. The symfony side is working, so the problem is somewhere in this JS.

What am I doing wrong?

Later edit:
I think I have an idea why this is not working. `digest` is an object and `salted` is a string. CryptoJS.SHA512 accepts both, but I don't think `digest + salted` is not what is expecting.

Comment: In your PHP code, `$iterations` has been unnecessarily set to a string. You can remove the quotes from around the `5000` here.

Comment: @halfer: I don't use the code I posted. This is an adaptation that I made base on Symfony's encoder. As I wrote in the post there may be possible typos in the PHP code... I want to replicate the response of the php code in js. thanks

Comment: Notwithstanding, if you remove the errors from your post to start with, it'll help focus readers on any other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that in PHP you initialize the loop in `1`:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $iterations; $i++)
```

but in JavaScript you initialize the loop in `0`:

```
for (var i=0;i<5000;i++)
```

Comment: Yes, typo too. The problem is that the initial digest is the same on both sides, only after it gets in the loop (from the 1st iteration), the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem is in here:

```
<?php
    $salted = $raw_pass."{"$salt."}";
?>
```

You forgot a dot ( . ), it should be this:

```
<?php
    $salted = $raw_pass."{".$salt."}";
?>
```

Also you start one time with 1 and one time with 0 (see post below)

Comment: The code I posted is a adaptation of [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php) for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix it so I had to change the strategy. Considering I'm encoding already encoded (and salted) data and I'm not providing the whole info to the user, I should be safe.

I changed to SHA1 and I'm using `btoa()` and `atobe()` JS functions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) since CryptoJS also provides that, it seems.

Comment: I already tried that, but for some reason I get different results.